# ISSUES IMPORTING MODELS

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hope anyone here would be able to help me out.

I'm trying to makemigrations but it's been impossible :/

I keep getting the following error:

> File
> "C:\Users\User\Documents\EBAC\Django\django\bookstore\order\models_*init*_.py",
> line 4, in 
> from .order import Order   File "C:\Users\User\Documents\EBAC\Django\django\bookstore\order\models\order.py",
> line 4, in 
> from product.models import Product ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'product.models'

as you can see on the the file structure I have 2 apps order and product, I am trying to import the Product model inside my Order model, but it keep saying that there is no module named 'product.models'

[image: file structure]

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

from product.models import Product


class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have declared both apps on the settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'order',
    'product',
]
```

and have also create the ****init****.py for the models folder:

```
from .category import Category
from .product import Product
```

I have the impression that all the set up is correct and also the code, but it's not working, if anyone could help me out to find the issue here I would strongly appreciate.

Thanks a lot

Comment: have you tried to do the makemigrations for a specific application ? say: `python manage.py makemigrations product`. Also make sure to register the model in admin.py file:
`admin.site.register(Product)`

Comment: Why is your models folder under product/models/ named models.py ?

Anyhow, I think you should try to make sure you have to correct path. Try adding another dot to your import

Answer (score 0):

Just got the answer...
by mistake I had put an extension '.py' on the folder **models**.

It was a silly mistake...

tks anyway